# Reset level count, Sphero 2.0

Tags: android, sphero-api

I bought Sphero as a present, but couldn't resist having a play.

I now want to package it back up, however I cannot find a way to reset the level count.

I finally found how to change the name (in the Super Advanced Settings), but I cannot see how to reset the levels back to zero.

Resetting the device using the reset button on the base does not do the job.

I spoke to Live Online Help, however they said I could not reset the levels as 'The moment Sphero is activated, he starts pushing data out immediately'.

I don't want this to be more trouble than its worth, but is there a way of using the API to completely reset the level count on the Sphero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the main sphero 2.0 app click into free play or level mode, click the cog for settings, tripple tap the white sphero on your screen (in the settings menu), this will take you to advanced settings, bottom of the screen tap the "reset soul" option.